# How can I get chrome to display an image list directly from the typed URL?

Tags: google-chrome

If I'm in DuckDuckGo, I can type

```
!images puppies
```

And get directly to the Google image list of a bunch of pictures of puppies.  But when I'm not using DuckDuckGo, I seem only able to first get to the main Google page, where a few teaser images are listed along with a bunch of text links, and then only if I click "View All" below the images can I see a whole scrolling list.  Is there a way, in Chrome, via a typed URL alone (no clicking another link needed) to access this page?  The URL at the top is always quite garbled.  I can see search terms, but I really want to know if there's something like:

```
images.google.com/?q=puppies
```

that will work. (Because that particular URL doesn't.)

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, you can get the exact same functionality in Chrome.

Go to chrome://settings/searchEngines (you can type this in the address bar directly, or navigate there via ... button -> settings -> search engine -> manage search engines).

Then click the "Add" button beside "Other Search Engines". Fill in "Google Images" as the search engine, "!images" as the keyword, and https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&hl=en&tbm=isch&sclient=img as the URL.

Now when you search "!images puppies" in the search bar, you'll get the same result. Feel free to choose a different keyword if you want to make the "!images" shortcut even faster to type.

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was hoping was out there.  So easy!  I spent so long trying to figure it out, too.  Yay!

Comment: I am now curious, how would I have known to use that long string with the %s tucked in there?  And is there a method for setting this up for, say, other things, like !alltrails and get a hike name we want to search?  Or does it only work for designated search engines?

Again, thrilled to know about this trick and it work's great.  I did find I could do one for !maps too, but I cheated because the !maps URL was already listed in the search options.  But for one that's not, can this be crafted by hand?

Comment: @confused the way to find the long string is to do a search on the site of interest, and see what "original URL" it takes you to. Then you'd replace the part of the url which contains you search query, with the %s. Some of the query parameters (https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/) will be "tokens", which are long gibberish unique identifiers; remove those. Ideally you'll remove as many query params as possible, you can guess and check by removing from that original URL until it no longer links to the search page in the way you'd expect. Good luck